# Parse Server // findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock // Array

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2, parse-server, pfquery

```
Parse Server: 2.2.17 (self hosted)  
Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX: 1.14.2  
ParseUI-iOS Version: 1.2.0  
Xcode 7.3.1, Swift
```

I'm new at iOS Programming (20 weeks) and build an App for fun and learning.

I have a problem with a Parse function `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` and `Array`. After completing my function will give me an array with the initial values. Inside the function i can see the values added to the array.

```
class UserOverview {

    var strings: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]

    init() {
        userKcal()
    }

    func userKcal() -> [String] {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "StringClassInParse")
        query.whereKey("userPointer", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in
            if let returnedObjects = objects {
                for object in returnedObjects {
                    let kcal = object["kcal"] as? String
                    self.strings.append(kcal!)
                }
            }
            print(self.strings) // output is ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
        }
        print(self.strings) // output is ["1", "2", "3"]
        return strings
    }
}
```

Any idea? + Sorry for this beginner question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `closures` with your function because you are making `block` and `block` will work in `async` manner, so that you need to declare your function with `closure` and then return the `String` array with that `closure`.

```
func userKcal(completion: ([String]) -> ()) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "StringClassInParse")
    query.whereKey("userPointer", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in
        if let returnedObjects = objects {
            for object in returnedObjects {
                let kcal = object["kcal"] as? String
                self.strings.append(kcal!)
            }
        }
        completion(self.strings)
    }
}
```

Now call this function like this way

```
self.userKcal { (strings) -> () in
     print(strings)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the code (musst analyse and learn it), but it work's like a charme. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you want to know more about this search like closure in swift.